# Trying to create a rectangular box within my image after using imshow in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst, region

I currently have an image where I want to highlight a particular area. As shown in the picture below. I do not need the coordinates to appear on the image. I know of two ways I can do this in `MATLAB`:

[image]

- Create an image of the same size, with the Area of Interest highlighted with a particular colour. Now superimpose this image with the original image.
- Create a complex `for` loop that highlights the edges with a particular colour.

But neither of this is convenient, as one of them loses some of the information of the image, while the other is quite cumbersome to implement. Therefore I wanted to know if there was a function that would let me do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Rectangle](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html) function of MATLAB?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how to use the function with imshow?

Comment: Just tried 'imshow('peppers.png');' and 'rectangle('Position',[0,0,100,100])' afterwards. That draws an rectangle at the given position

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to using `rectangle`, you can use the `insertShape` function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox. `insertShape` can draw a semi-transparent filled rectangle directly into the image.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should get you there.

```
imshow(img); %// without the quotes 
rectangle('Position',[ bottomLeft_xcoord bottomLeft_ycoord width height])
```

The MATLAB doc for `rectangle` gives more details on the parameters.
You can find it here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html